# How to pass variables from a decorator with arguments to a pytest unit test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, decorator

Let's say I'm doing some unit tests with pytest that need some configuration. And let's say that I also want to add some custom configuration, depending on the unit test I'm trying to create.

So, I have currently the following:

```py
import pytest

def load_configuration(custom_config=None):
    """Loads some default configuration, and if necessary injects some custom configuration"""
    config = some_complicated_stuff()
    if custom_config:
        config.update(custom_config)
    return config


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def foo():
    return 69


def test_bar_long_way(foo):
    config = load_configuration(custom_config={"bar": 42})
    assert foo == 69
    assert config[bar] == 42
    # do stuff with foo and config
```

Is there a way to inject that custom configuration into the unit test using a decorator (let's call it `load_config`), rather than having to create the configuration within the unit test itself? In this simplified example it's quite short, but in reality this takes a bit more space. I'm looking for a way to make it look like this:

```py
@load_config({"bar": 42})
def test_bar_with_decorator(config, foo):
    assert foo == 69
    assert config["bar"] == 42
    # do stuff with foo and config
```

I can't figure out how to create this `load_config` decorator. Any help would be appreciated :).

Comment: The name `bar` is undefined here.  Did you mean the string `"bar"` instead?

Comment: Yes, of course, wim! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pytest


def some_complicated_stuff():
    return {"abc": 123}


def load_configuration(custom_config=None):
    """Loads some default configuration, and if necessary injects some custom configuration"""
    config = some_complicated_stuff()
    if custom_config:
        config.update(custom_config)
    return config


@pytest.mark.parametrize('config', [load_configuration({"bar": 42})])
def test_bar_long_way(config):
    assert config["bar"] == 42
    # do stuff with foo and config
```

[`parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html) is usually used for running the same test function but given different values for its parameters, but we can use it to run only once.

If you prefer having a nicer decorator :

```
def custom_config(config_val):
    return pytest.mark.parametrize('config', [load_configuration(config_val)])


@custom_config({"bar": 42})
def test_bar_long_way(config):
    assert config["bar"] == 42
```